# Evaluate: $\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\pi\cos^2x\right)}{x^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to evaluate the following limit without using *L'Hospital's rule*?

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\pi\cos^2x\right)}{x^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you're willling to take

Heuristically $\cos(x)\sim 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2$ and so $\cos(x)^2\sim 1-x^2$. Thus, if $L$ denotes your limit:

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(\pi-\pi x^2)}{x^2}=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(\pi x^2)}{x^2}=-\pi$$

where the last equality follows from substitution $\pi x^2\mapsto t$ and the (common) fact that

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan(t)}{t}=1$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\tan(\pi \cos^2(x)) = \tan(\pi - \pi \sin^2(x)) = - \tan(\pi \sin^2(x))$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan(\pi \cos^2(x))}{x^2}=- \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\tan(\pi \sin^2(x))}{x^2} = - \pi$$

Comment: That last step is sort of an leap. You sort of need the step $$\dfrac{\tan(\pi \sin^2(x))}{x^2} = \pi\dfrac{\tan(\pi\sin^2(x))}{\pi\sin^2(x)}\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\tan(\pi\cos^2x)}{x^2}=\frac{\tan(\pi-\pi\sin^2x)}{x^2}=-\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi\sin^2x)}\frac{\sin(\pi\sin^2x)}{\pi\sin^2x}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\to-\frac\pi1\cdot1\cdot1.$$

Comment: Very nice. Compliments.